# How to generate all files when making a new directory using "rails new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I use `rails new` to create a new projet with Rails 6.0.2.2, Rails generates only these files:

```
c:\Users\computer>rails new .
       exist
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
```

I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `rails new` command expects a name for the directory to generate the application in (which also becomes the application name), but `.` seems to not be acceptable.

Try invoking the command like this:

```
rails new my_app_name
```

It could also be that it is trying to initialize a git repository and fails. Hard to tell from the output of your post whether that finishes or not. Maybe you don't have git installed, or maybe there's a problem with the command (maybe you are already inside another git repository?). You could try to skip that part only by passing the `--skip-git` flag:

```
rails new --skip-git my_app_name
```

Comment: . is for installing in the durrent dir, yes the problem is because git is not installed thank you for your response ;)